# MacRuby can't link controller to new window xib

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nswindow, macruby, nswindowcontroller

**My Setup**

- XCode 4.3.2
- MacRuby 0.12 (ruby 1.9.2) [universal-darwin10.0, x86_64]

  - Latest nightly as of 4 Jun, 2012
- OS 10.7.3

**Goal**

Have a window with some controls in a separate XIB from MainMenu.xib and be able to open that window programmatically. I do not want it to open at launch.

**Attempts**

1. I made a new xib (Woot.xib) and created a window in it
2. I made a new Ruby class

   ```
   class WootController < NSWindowController
       attr_accessor :window
       def windowNibName
            return 'Woot'
       end
   end
   ```
3. I tried to set the class of File's Owner in the Woot.xib to be WootController, but found that it **will not** if `< NSWindowController` is in my class definition. If I remove the `< NSWindowController` from the class definition,  then the outlets populate and I can link the window in XIB to the window outlet in my class.
4. From inside my AppDelegate's `applicationDidFinishLaunching` method, I've tried

   *Attempt*

   ```
   newWind = WootController.new
   puts newWind #outputs "#<AddCredentialsDialog:0x400191180>"
   newWind.window().makeKeyAndOrderFront(self) # results in no method error for nil
   ```

   *Attempt 2*

   ```
   newWind = WootController.initWithWindowNibName 'AddWindow'
   puts newWind #outputs "#<AddCredentialsDialog:0x400191180>"
   newWind.window().makeKeyAndOrderFront(self) # results in no method error for nil
   ```

**Questions**

1. Why don't either of my attempts work? I've ready just about everything I can find on macruby and using NSWindowController.
2. Why can't I link my class `WootController` if I have it inheriting from `NSWindowController`
3. Is there a different way to do this **other than putting it all in MainMenu.xib**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution works

```
nib = NSNib.alloc.initWithNibNamed('Woot', bundle: nil)
newWind = WootController.new
nib.instantiateNibWithOwner(newWind, topLevelObjects:nil)
newWind.showWindow(self)
```

Some things to note

1. In Macruby, if there are named parameters to a method signature, you **must** use them even if you just specify nil or the method signatures don't match up and you get a `no method` error.

   ie. `obj.foo('hello', to_whom: nil)` is not the same as `obj.foo('hello')`
2. If there are named parameters you **must** use parentheses.

   ie. **this** `obj.foo('hello', to_whom: nil)` will work, **not this** `obj.foo 'hello', to_whom: nil`